# How do browsers handle "@" within the url domain?

Tags: redirect, http-redirect

If you access this url `https://stackoverflow.com@duckduckgo.com/` it takes you to duckduckgo. If you try to `curl`, it will still return duckduckgo html.

I couldn't find any explanation or RFC for this behavior. What is happening behind the scene? Why is `stackoverflow.com` part ignored completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In URL resolving `@` is normally used for delimiting **user** and **host** information.

I think until `@` everything is parsed as `user info`, then for defining the `host` the rest is used.

See:

- [some weird draft from IETF, where google led me](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-abarth-url-00.html#rfc.section.3.3)
- [a serverfault related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters)

Also, [RFC-1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) contains the following about reserved characters:

```
   Many URL schemes reserve certain characters for a special meaning:
   their appearance in the scheme-specific part of the URL has a
   designated semantics. If the character corresponding to an octet is
   reserved in a scheme, the octet must be encoded.  The characters ";",
   "/", "?", ":", "@", "=" and "&" are the characters which may be
   reserved for special meaning within a scheme. No other characters may
   be reserved within a scheme.
```

And finally from [RFC-3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

```
authority   = [ userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ]
```

Make sure to read `3.2. Authority section` and `3.2.1.  User Information` parts.